# Unable to store data in mysql using AJAX, jQuery and php in Phonegap android

Tags: php, android, jquery, mysql, cordova

I am developing an application using phonegap. I am trying to connect mysql database to phonegap to save data from html5 page using Ajax, php and jquery. But I am unable to save data in mySql database. Is there anything wrong in the below code..?? This is my Html and php code below :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>MySQL Database with Phonegap</title>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>

        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script>
            $('form').submit(function()
            {
                var postData = $(this).serialize();

                $.ajax(
                {
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: postData,
                    url: 'http://localhost/Save.php',
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        console.log(data);
                        alert('Your data was successfully added');
                    },
                    error: function()
                    {
                        console.log(data);
                        alert('There was an error adding your comment');
                    }
            });
                return false;
        });
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
            <h1 align="center">Database Connectivity</h1><br><br><br>
            <div align="center">
                <form>

                <label><b>First Name :</b></label><br>
                <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"/><br>
                <label><b>Last Name :</b></label><br>
                <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"/><br>
                <label><b>Email ID :</b></label><br>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email"/><br><br>
                <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type="reset" value="RESET"/>
                </form>
            </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

---

### Save.php

```
<?php
    $host='localhost';
    $uname='root';
    $pwd='xyz';
    $db='Sample';

    $con=mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pwd) or die("Connection Failed");
    mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die("database selection failed");

    $fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);
    $lname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lname']);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

    //echo "Hello";

    $flag['code']=0;

    if($r=mysql_query("INSERT INTO Login (FirstName, LastName, Email) VALUES ('".$fname."','".$lname."','".$email."')",$con))
    {
        $flag['code']=1;
        echo "okk...";
    }
    print(json_encode($flag));
    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: check apache log for any php error

Comment: sorry...!!! but there's no error in php code. If I hardcode the values then this will save into database. And I am using Ubuntu.

Comment: try to echo the query and see if every values are received properly and execute the same query into mysql

Comment: I said, no problem in php code. query is working fine in mysql.

Comment: Oh ok.I mean to check whether the ajax value are passed to php page

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://yourphpfilehere.php?PARAMETERSHERE=" + javascriptvariable,
    success: function(res) {
        alert(res);
    }
});
```

and in your php file, I suggest if you use like this:

```
$myvariable = $_REQUEST['URLPARAMETER'];

//do the mysql statement,proccess here . . .
```

you should access the variable from php script with $_REQUEST method since you are going to request on that php file. dont make your code complicated man